# Connect oracle 11g client from windows 7 to Windows server 2008

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Good afternoon dear all. I am Shaiju.I need your advice on installing Oracle 11g database client software in my windows 7 64 bit OS workstation. The following is my scenario.

1. I have installed Oracle Database 11g 64 bit on my server (Windows 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit). It works well.
2. I have to access the database from my client machine (Windows 7 64bit). I have installed oracle database 32 bit client in the workstation. I chose Administrator mode method while installing the oracle client software.
3. I copied tnsnames.ora, listener.ora from the server and pasted them in workstation under network\admin folder.

When I tried to connect the database through sqlplus, it could not connect the database. It says "Error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener".

If you have any idea what could be the problem, please advise me how to sort it out.

Comment: maybe the oracle services not running?

Answer (score 1):

First I'll assume that the listener and database are up on your server (you can see them as windows services). If you don't know what you are doing I'd strongly recommend using the the oracle configuration assistant to modify the tns files and always keep a backup. They are very sensitive if you don't get the syntax right.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B16276_01/doc/server.102/b14196/network005.htm

You could also try easyconnect http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/naming.htm#i498306